# Error while configuring multiple Navigation Properties to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having a weird issue with multiple navigation Properties to the same table.

My FuelBunkerType POCO class is configured like the following:

```
    public class FuelBunkerType : IEventReportElement
{

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeKey { get; set; }        
    public string TypeValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? Sulphur { get; set; }
    public decimal? Water { get; set; }
    public decimal? Viscosity { get; set; }
    public decimal? Density { get; set; }
    public string BdnNumber { get; set; }
    public long? IdEventReport { get; set; }
    public long? DeactivatedByIdEventReport { get; set; }

    public IList<FuelBunkerQuantity> FuelBunkerQuantitys { get; set; }
    public EventReport EventReport { get; set; }
    public EventReport DeactivatedByEventReport { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext, my class is configured like:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerType>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        if (_writeversion) modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerType>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        else modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerType>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerType>().HasRequired(x => x.EventReport).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.IdEventReport);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerType>().HasOptional(x => x.DeactivatedByEventReport).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.DeactivatedByIdEventReport);
```

So far, so good. It actually worked like this until friday. However, when I try to fetch data from the table now, the resulting Query looks like

```
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[TypeKey] AS [TypeKey], 
[Extent1].[TypeValue] AS [TypeValue], 
[Extent1].[Sulphur] AS [Sulphur], 
[Extent1].[Water] AS [Water], 
[Extent1].[Viscosity] AS [Viscosity], 
[Extent1].[Density] AS [Density], 
[Extent1].[BdnNumber] AS [BdnNumber], 
[Extent1].[IdEventReport] AS [IdEventReport], 
[Extent1].[DeactivatedByIdEventReport] AS [DeactivatedByIdEventReport], 
[Extent1].[EventReport_Id] AS [EventReport_Id]
FROM [FuelBunkerType] AS [Extent1]}
```

which obviously results in a "column name is not valid" error, so my first Configuration line (Entity().HasRequired(x=>x.EventReport)...) is ignored.
I tried out commenting out the Configuration for DeactivatedByEventReport, it resulted in the same query except for DeactivatedByEventReport_Id (like expected), it only happens with multiple Navigation Properties to the same table.
However, when I add more navigation properties to EventReport, it only mistakenly queries for EventReport_Id, so only the first one seems to be ignored when there are multiple navigation properties.

Any ideas why this happens, and what to do to solve this? Greetings

EDIT: For the other classes corresponding to this, there are the following Fluent API configs:

```
if (_writeversion) modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        else modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.MaxEventTimeLt);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.MaxEventTimeUtc);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.MinEventTimeLt);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.MinEventTimeUtc);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.EventReportElementTyps);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.EventsWithUpdatedSortNumber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.EventTimeUtcLoaded);
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventReport>().Ignore(x => x.HasChanged);

      modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        if (_writeversion) modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        else modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().HasOptional(x => x.FuelBunkerType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.IdFuelBunkerType);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().HasOptional(x => x.EventReport).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.IdEventReport);
        modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().Ignore(x => x.EventReport);
```

The Configs on EventReport shouldn't effect anything, as you can see I disabled the navigation property on FuelBunkerQuantity to try if this was causing the error, but it didn't change the Error or the resulting Query in the slightest.

EDIT2: The class EventReport:

```
public class EventReport
{
    public long Id { get; set; }


    public long? SortNumber { get; set; }
    public string ReportType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationTimeUtc { get; set; }


    public DateTime? EventTimeUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventTimeUtcLoaded { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventTimeLt { get; set; }
    public long? EventDuration { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastSendAtUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastSendAtLt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstSendAtUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstSendAtLt { get; set; }
    public string EventQualityState { get; set; }
    public bool IsDraft { get; set; }

    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public IEnumerable<FuelBunkerRob> FuelRoB { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public IEnumerable<OilBunkerRob> OilRoB { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public List<FuelBunkerType> ActiveFuelTypes { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public DateTime? MaxEventTimeUtc { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public DateTime? MaxEventTimeLt { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public DateTime? MinEventTimeUtc { get; set; }
    [IgnoreOnEqualCheck]
    public DateTime? MinEventTimeLt { get; set; }


    public List<EventReport> EventsWithUpdatedSortNumber {get; set;}


    public long? ConfigurationId { get; set; }


    public bool HasChanged { get; set; }
    public List<IEventReportElement> EventReportElements { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT3: I just skipped the Statement which was causing the error. Turns out FuelBunkerQuantity has wrong Translation as well (see configuration in Edit):

```
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[IdFuelBunkerType] AS [IdFuelBunkerType], 
[Extent1].[MassDelta] AS [MassDelta], 
[Extent1].[MassAbsolut] AS [MassAbsolut], 
[Extent1].[IdEventReport] AS [IdEventReport], 
[Extent1].[FuelBunkerType_Id] AS [FuelBunkerType_Id]
FROM [FuelBunkerQuantity] AS [Extent1]}
```

Seems like something is broken, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Are you showing all the fluent API configs here or are you configuring the other entities? I suspect there is a conflicting one that is overriding this one.

Comment: These are all the fluent API configs for FuelBunkerType. In FuelBunkerQuantity, I configure the navigation property to table FuelBunkerType, EventReport has no necessary configs.

Comment: Does the `EventReport` model class have any collections of `FuelBunkerType`?

Comment: Because the `WithMany()` method has an overload to map those collections to the correct relationship

Comment: no, it doesn't. EventReport has a collection of IEventReportElements (of which FuelBunkerType is derived), but this is not mapped into the database (otherwhise I would've used TPC inheritance, but it's not possible because IEventReportElement is an interface)

Comment: Could yo post the code for the `EventReport` class?

Comment: See the end of my original post. Also nothing with too high impact.

Comment: I've just tried to recreate the issue without success. I correctly get the right foreign key. I am a little bit clueless as to what's going on in your case. I know it's clutching at straws but the config line is definitely not in the else block is it?

Comment: it isn't. I also just made the else statement into it's own block of code, the error still persists. and actually, it was working with the same configuration for me as well, until today. no clue either there.

Comment: I've just noticed your recent edit. Your `EventReport` does have a collection of `FuelTypes`. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, there is. but I can't use these, because they do not have the correct IdEventReport in it - they are just runtime variables used for plausibility.

Comment: I can't see where you're telling EF to ignore this property?

Comment: Could you try using the `NotMapped` attribute and see if that works?

Comment: Hey... yes, that actually worked! thank you

Comment: Brilliant - glad it worked. It took some figuring out :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are configuring two one-to-may relationships between `EventReport` and `FuelBunkerType` and there is only one collection on the many side EF can't match the relationships. Depending on which relationship the collection property `ActiveFuelTypes` belongs to you can explicitly map it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FuelBunkerQuantity>().
             HasOptional(x => x.FuelBunkerType).
             WithMany(e => e.ActiveFuelTypes).
             HasForeignKey(x => x.IdFuelBunkerType);
```

Comment: to anyone stumbling across this problem: I either had to give EF the inverse property (.WithMany(x=>x.ActiveFuelTypes)), or ignore the possible navigation property. Seems like EF got confused as to what to use for each navigation property, so it didnt use anything at all.