# How to configure an OData v4 model to have multiple navigation props to the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I have an Ownership class with two navigation properties that each reference a ContactInfo object, one for the owner property, and one for the emergency contact property.

```
[Table ("A_OWNERSHIP")]
public class Ownership {

    public Ownership() {}

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("OWNER_ID")]
    public int ownerID { get; set; }

    [Column("EMERGENCY_CONTACT_ID")]
    public int? emergencyContactID { get; set; }

    // ** other members ellided **

    public virtual ContactInfo owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ContactInfo emergencyContact { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to get the collection of ownerships through my OData service URL:

```
http://localhost:52283/odata/Ownership
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00904: \"Extent1\".\"ContactInfo_ID\": invalid identifier","type":"Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException"
```

I gather that this error is similar to what's happening in this question:

[Error while configuring multiple Navigation Properties to same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786022/error-while-configuring-multiple-navigation-properties-to-same-table)

The problem is that I'm using OData v4, which references System.Web.OData.Builder and not System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.  This means that answers (like in the linked question) saying to use Fluent API to configure the Entity using the WithMany() call fails, because there is no WithMany() call in System.Web.OData.Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the related object needed their related collection properties decorated with the InverseProperty attribute:

```
public class ContactInfo {

    public ContactInfo() {

        this.owners = new HashSet<Ownership>();
        this.emergencyContacts = new HashSet<Ownership>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // *** other members ellided ***    

    [InverseProperty("owner")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ownership> owners { get; private set; }

    [InverseProperty("emergencyContact")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ownership> emergencyContacts { get; private set; }
}
```