# Why is Entity Framework looking for the wrong foreign key column?

Tags: entity-framework

I've seen various questions on related topics, which seem like they would address my issue, but nothing I try seems to help.

I have an EF (6.1.3) model of an existing DB, which has been working fine.  I've just added an additional column to a table, which represents a new relationship.  Perhaps relevantly, the relationship is the second one between the two tables - the original `Location` is now joined by `ActualDirectSite`, both of them relating the `Uniform` and `Location` tables.

The moment I added the two new properties, `ActualDirectSiteID` and `ActualDirectSite`, my SELECT queries started failing with the error "Invalid column name 'Location_ID'".   It's true that that column doesn't exist, but I don't see why EF is looking for it - it was happy before, but something has made it think the column name should be different.  The failing name makes me think it's the original Location which is somehow no longer working.

Here's the Entity in question:

```
public partial class Uniform
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("LocationID")]
    public int? LocationID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocationID")]
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public int? ActualDirectSiteID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ActualDirectSiteID")]
    public virtual Location ActualDirectSite { get; set; }
}
```

And my (shortened) table def:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Uniforms](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationID] [int] NULL,
    [ActualDirectSiteID] [int] NULL)
```

The obvious solution to relying on convention causing incorrect assumptions about column names is to specify them explicitly, and so I've tried using `Column` annotations, and also to make sure that the ID and navigation properties know about each other using `ForeignKey`, but no dice.  Any ideas?

EDIT: added missing LocationID field (already present in full code)

EDIT2: to be clear, before I added `ActualDirectSiteID` to the Entity it all worked fine, with no annotations required.  I've just had another look at the generated SQL, and it seems like the `Location_ID` reference corresponds to the `ActualDirectSite` property:

```
//[Extent1] is "Uniform"
... , [Extent1].[LocationID] AS [LocationID], [Extent1].[ActualDirectSiteID] AS [ActualDirectSiteID], [Extent1].[Location_ID] AS [Location_ID], //...[Extent4] begins
```

EDIT3: I didn't include any of my `Location` entity, here it is:

```
[Table("Location")]
public partial class Location
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Uniform> Uniforms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The ForeignKey Attribute is used to address existing properties as used fk properties. The actual name of the FK is not specified there (as there is no property a mapped column name could be assigned to). You'll have to actually create the FK property, and if you want the column name to differ, you can use the [Column] attribute.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake when preparing the question - there was in fact already a property called `LocationID`, with a Column attribute.  Even so, EF is looking for `Location_ID` (with underscore).  Before I introduced `ActualDirectSiteID`, `Location` worked without any additional Annotations.

Comment: with two navigation properties to the same table, you'll need to define the inverse navigation property for at least one of those (if I remember correctly)

Comment: That's it!  I had `public virtual ICollection<Uniform> Uniforms` in my `Location` entity, and EF wouldn't have known which `Uniform` property to map it to, and just had a guess or something.  Would have been nicer to have had some hint from EF, but glad we tracked it down.  Thank you, if you add an Answer along these lines I'll accept it.

Comment: The same problem occurs if the data types of the foreign key and the key of the referenced table mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments: with multiple navigation properties to the same table, EF will get confused as to which navigation property refers to which inverse navigation property and **ignore** the FK mapping of those. A similar issue I stumbled across some time ago can be found [in this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786022/error-while-configuring-multiple-navigation-properties-to-same-table)

There are only two ways (I know of) to fix this issue:

- Ignore at least all but one of the navigation properties with [NotMapped] or .Ignore() or
- Add a inverse navigation property to (at least) all but one navigation properties to this table and adjust the mapping accordingly.

Actually, this behavior smells like a bug on EF side (from a DB point of view, I don't see the problem there), but the workaround is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

By convention every foreign key declaration include 2 properties.
If you create link to Location entity, then you must add property with name - LocationId type int. That is why you got an error
ForeignKey annotation is used to specify the name of used int id property for link (if you plan to use different name)
You  can declare foreign key only like here:

```
public Location Location {get; set;}
public int LocationId {get; set;}
```

Or like here:

```
[ForeignKey("CustomIdProperty")]
public Location Location {get; set;}
public int CustomIdProperty {get; set;}
```

(Pardon me for possible typos - writting from phone)

Comment: My apologies, my example wasn't complete - I did in fact have both the LocationID and Location properties in my entity definition

Comment: Column annotation is not needed in that case. It is needed for mapped columns only, but not constraints.